# Why does this functional integral yield only an endpoint contribution?

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Consider the functional integral

$$
J(\epsilon) = \int\limits_c^{c+\epsilon} F(x,y_\epsilon(x),y_\epsilon'(x))\,dx
$$

where $\epsilon<<c$; $x$ is the independent variable; $y_\epsilon(x)$ is a piecewise function independent of $\epsilon$ for $c<x<c+\epsilon$; $y_\epsilon'(x)$ the derivative of $y_\epsilon(x)$ with respect to $x$ and is also piecewise independent of $\epsilon$ for $c<x<c+\epsilon$.

A book that I am currently reading states that, "because $F(x,y_\epsilon(x),y_\epsilon'(x))$ is independent of $\epsilon$ for $c<x<c+\epsilon$, differentiating $J$ with respect to $\epsilon$ yields only an endpoint contribution:

$$
J'(\epsilon)=F(c+\epsilon,y_\epsilon(c+\epsilon),y_\epsilon'(c+\epsilon))
$$

**Why is this true?** The only way that I can make sense of this would be if

$$
J(\epsilon) =F(c+\epsilon,y_\epsilon(c+\epsilon),y_\epsilon'(c+\epsilon))(c+\epsilon) - F(c,y_\epsilon(c),y_\epsilon'(c))c
$$

then

$$
J'(\epsilon)=F(c+\epsilon,y_\epsilon(c+\epsilon),y_\epsilon'(c+\epsilon))\frac{\partial (c+\epsilon)}{\partial \epsilon}=F(c+\epsilon,y_\epsilon(c+\epsilon),y_\epsilon'(c+\epsilon))
$$

which is the result found in the book, but since $F(x,y_\epsilon(x),y_\epsilon'(x))$ is not independent of $x$, I do not see how this would be possible. Also, if I apply Leibniz's rule to differentiate $J$, it starts off as

$$
J'(\epsilon) = \int\limits_c^{c+\epsilon} \frac{\partial F(x,y_\epsilon(x),y_\epsilon'(x))}{\partial \epsilon}\,dx = \int\limits_c^{c+\epsilon} \left\{ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y_\epsilon}\frac{\partial y_\epsilon}{\partial \epsilon} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y_\epsilon'}\frac{\partial y_\epsilon'}{\partial \epsilon} \right\}dx
$$

by the chain rule. However, since both $y_\epsilon$ and $y_\epsilon'$ are independent of $x$ for $c<x<c+\epsilon$, the bracketed term should be zero. How is the result from the book obtained then?